# Vim: Warning: Output not to a terminal

Tags: python, c++, unix, vim, sh

I am running a C++ binary which runs a python script. I do this in the following way

```
stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
if (stream) {
  while (!feof(stream))
    if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) != NULL) data.append(buffer);
  status = pclose(stream);
}
```

This python script also runs some shell commands using subprocess

```
subprocess.check_call(arg_list)
```

Suddenly I have started getting errors like "Vim: Warning: Output not to a terminal" and the C++ binary hangs.

What is the easiest way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The `popen` call is going to read whatever the subprocess writes to its standard output.  Some of that is likely useful (such as status messages).  You would not get useful results from vim's standard output, because it would be partly escape sequences (for moving the cursor, changing the colors).

If you can modify the script so that it handles vim specially, there is a fix: modify the commands which run vim so that they redirect to `/dev/tty`.  That would change a command-string that looks like this

```
vim filename
```

to

```
vim filename >/dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
export TERM=vt100
```

before you call Perl or as the first command in each Unix subprocess.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Could you explain this more?

Comment: @FDinoff On AIX sed does not have an -i option for changing a file without a tmp file. I used a here-construction with vi to edit the file, redirecting stdout/stderr to /dev/null. The remote installation scripts that worked on Solaris failed on AIX with an error message about the terminal. In my case I could solve the installation script problems by adding `TERM=vt100`